# Gstreamer negotiation with videoconvert

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer

We are getting unexpected behaviour when using `videoconvert` with `gst-launch`:

On doing option (1) below we get errors:

```
  gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src !  'video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1'  ! autovideosink
```

The erros is:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data flow error. Additional debug info: gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop():/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
```

The error does make sense, because probably the format of filter does not match format of `v4l2src` or format of `autovideosink`.

But by using  videoconvert in both options (2&3) below, it works OK without any errors:

I see that option (2) below works without any errors:

```
  gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src !  videoconvert !   'video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1'  ! autovideosink
```

I also see that option (3) below works without any errors:

```
  gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src  !   'video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1'  ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

The question is why is works in both cases (2&3).

I would assume that it should only work in one of them because if src of `v4l2src`  does not match filter(width=640, height=480) then we must convert the format of `v4l2src`  to match filter.

On the other hand, if the format of  `autovideosink` does not match filter (width=640, height=480) then we must do the conversion right after the filter.

So, I would assume that only (2) or (3) should work but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) and (3) can work because this could actually be an issue with the format of your video. The likely reason is that your camera produces some format and your video sink cannot accept it. Adding `videoconvert` in the middle makes it convert from one to another and them they are happy.

To negotiate, `videoconvert` gets the downstream caps and propagates them upstream, except that it injects more formats than downstream can handle because it can accept a different one and then just convert. The dimension and framerate are kept as is because nothing in that pipeline can scale or change the rate.

If you run the working pipeline with `-v` flag it should print the actual negotiated caps and then you can see what v4l2src produces on its source pad and what the video sink receives in its sink pad. Then you can see what exactly videoconvert is converting.

Comment: I am not sure why option (3) for example works. If v4l2src  has no option to output the caps filter format ( width=640, height=480) , and converter is done *only afterwards*, then why should the pipeline pass the caps filter ?

Comment: The caps filter doesn't specify a format. Only the resolution is enforced and your camera works with it.

Comment: You can check `gst-inspect-1.0 videoconvert` to see the various formats that videoconvert supports and can convert from/to.